# Image blurs only at some parts not all

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to blur an image.

I am using a kernel called `k[][3]= { 1, .01, 1, .01, 0, .01, 1, .01, 1};`

The code is as follows:

```
void blur(IplImage *notgray)
{
    IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(notgray), notgray->depth, 1);
    cvCvtColor(notgray, img, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    int rows=img->height,cols=img->width,row,col,i,j,ki,kj;
    uchar* temp_ptr=0 ;
    float sum,k[][3]= { 1, .01, 1,
                    .01, 0, .01,
                     1, .01, 1};

    for( row = 0; row < rows; ++row) 
    {
            sum=0;
            for ( col = 0; col < cols; ++col) 
            {               
                            temp_ptr  = &((uchar*)(img->imageData + (img->widthStep*row)))[col];
                            for( j=-1,ki=0; j<=1;j++,ki++)
                            {
                                for( i=-1,kj=0; i<=1;i++,kj++)
                                {
                                    int x2=col+i;
                                    int y2=row+j;
                                    if ( x2>=0 && x2<img->width && y2>=0 && y2<img->height) 
                                    {
                                        sum=sum+k[ki][kj];
                                    if (sum<0) sum=0; else if (sum>255) sum=255;
                                    temp_ptr[0]  =(uchar) sum;

                                    }
                                }
                            }
            }

    }
}
```

I know the output really depends on my algorithm, but looking at the code and output i would request some guidance what i should do further to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set sum = 0; at the wrong place. Since it is only reset at the start of each row, each pixel will be whiter and whiter and...

Comment: Two lines further down. Looking at it I now see that "temp_ptr[0]  =(uchar) sum;" should really go down four lines for performance reasons.

Comment: You're right. Looking further at your code I really can't see how it is supposed to work at all. Have you just foud some code on the net that you're fiddling with without understanding any of it? You make no use what so ever of the pixels in the source image. Whatever image you will input to your code will produce exactly the same result!

Comment: Please have a look here i changed my source code a bit:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891561/convolution-to-blur-the-image-produces-a-sketchy-output-image

Comment: In that other code, you are correctly using values from the source imgage by calling cvGet2D(img,row,col); . You do no such thing in this code.

Comment: @danbystron - thanks... your input really helped, can you tell me how i can do the same without using cvGet2D...i.e. the way we use `img->imageData + (img->widthStep*row)))[col]` , can it be achieved by this?

Comment: Yes. You're spot on! It would be something like img->imageData + (img->widthStep*(row+i))))[col+j]; . (Note that this can be greatly optimized, with a little extra work). Don't you forget to upvote and accept, now! ;-)

Comment: i did have a go to do what you said, please help me out with this - here is the link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907775/how-to-load-nearby-pixels-using-pointer