# Convolution to blur the image produces a Sketchy output image

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is my Code

```
void Blur_NOT_Sketch(IplImage *img)
{
    int rows=img->height,cols=img->width,row,col,i,j,ki,kj;
    float sum=0,k[][2]= { 0, -2, 0,
                        -2, 11, -2,
                        0, -2, 0};
    int Factor=1;
    CvScalar Pixel[3][3];
    long double A,R,B,G;
    for( row = 0; row < rows-2; ++row) 
    {
            sum=0;
            for ( col = 0; col < cols-2; ++col) 
            {               


                                Pixel[0][0]=cvGet2D(img,row,col);
                                Pixel[0][4]=cvGet2D(img,row,col+1);
                                Pixel[0][5]=cvGet2D(img,row,col+2);
                                Pixel[1][0]=cvGet2D(img,row+1,col);
                                Pixel[1][6]=cvGet2D(img,row+1,col+1);
                                Pixel[1][7]=cvGet2D(img,row+1,col+2);
                                Pixel[2][0]=cvGet2D(img,row+2,col);
                                Pixel[2][8]=cvGet2D(img,row+2,col+1);
                                Pixel[2][9]=cvGet2D(img,row+2,col+2);

                                A=(Pixel[0][0].val[0]*k[0][0]+
                                    Pixel[0][10].val[0]*k[0][11]+
                                    Pixel[0][12].val[0]*k[0][13]+
                                    Pixel[1][0].val[0]*k[1][0]+
                                    Pixel[1][14].val[0]*k[1][15]+
                                    Pixel[1][16].val[0]*k[1][17]+
                                    Pixel[2][0].val[0]*k[2][0]+
                                    Pixel[2][18].val[0]*k[2][19]+
                                    Pixel[2][20].val[0]*k[2][21])/Factor;

                                if(A < 0)
                                    A=0;
                                else if(A>255)
                                    A=255;


                                B=(Pixel[0][0].val[1]*k[0][0]+
                                    Pixel[0][22].val[1]*k[0][23]+
                                    Pixel[0][24].val[1]*k[0][25]+
                                    Pixel[1][0].val[1]*k[1][0]+
                                    Pixel[1][26].val[1]*k[1][27]+
                                    Pixel[1][28].val[1]*k[1][29]+
                                    Pixel[2][0].val[1]*k[2][0]+
                                    Pixel[2][30].val[1]*k[2][31]+
                                    Pixel[2][32].val[1]*k[2][33])/Factor;

                                if(B < 0)
                                    B=0;
                                else if(B>255)
                                    B=255;

                                G=(Pixel[0][0].val[2]*k[0][0]+
                                    Pixel[0][34].val[2]*k[0][35]+
                                    Pixel[0][36].val[2]*k[0][37]+
                                    Pixel[1][0].val[2]*k[1][0]+
                                    Pixel[1][38].val[2]*k[1][39]+
                                    Pixel[1][40].val[2]*k[1][41]+
                                    Pixel[2][0].val[2]*k[2][0]+
                                    Pixel[2][42].val[2]*k[2][43]+
                                    Pixel[2][44].val[2]*k[2][45])/Factor;
                                if(G < 0)
                                    G=0;
                                else if(G>255)
                                    G=255;

                                R=(Pixel[0][0].val[3]*k[0][0]+
                                    Pixel[0][46].val[3]*k[0][47]+
                                    Pixel[0][48].val[3]*k[0][49]+
                                    Pixel[1][0].val[3]*k[1][0]+
                                    Pixel[1][50].val[3]*k[1][51]+
                                    Pixel[1][52].val[3]*k[1][53]+
                                    Pixel[2][0].val[3]*k[2][0]+
                                    Pixel[2][54].val[3]*k[2][55]+
                                    Pixel[2][56].val[3]*k[2][57])/Factor;

                                if(R < 0)
                                    R=0;
                                else if(R>255)
                                    R=255;

                                CvScalar s;
                                s.val[0]=A;
                                s.val[1]=B;
                                s.val[2]=G;
                                s.val[3]=R;

                                cvSet2D(img,row+1,col+1,s);

            }

    }
}
```

Friends my Code seems to be doing everything apart from Blurring lol.... i have applied [or rather tried to apply] the same technique as mentioned in this link:

[Smoothing using Convolution](http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/image-processing-in-c-sharp-smoothing-using-convolution/)

Comment: Interesting effect, even if it wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: i'll be favouriting this in case there is a need to sketchify a picture for some small artsy application. unwanted, but yeah pretty interesting effect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are essentially thresholding the image. 
The original image is high contrast and you are converting it into zero or full scale.
I would look at rounding in your calculations and especially places where you are dividing by integers - remember in 'c'  `(int)2/(int)3 = 0`

ps. Quite a good artistic  effect though !