# Implementation of Image Convolution (Image Processing) in C

Tags: c, image-processing, implementation, bmp

I am testing some convolution algorithms i found in some sites but none of them apply the matrix filters as it should.

I am writing a very simple 24 bits bmp library on my own, but now i need a little help with the convolution, i don't need FFT or complex algorithm, running time is not important at this time.

The last code i was testing was this: http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html But i didn't work fine.

Could some one indicate me a code or algorithm in C?.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this algorithm - this is the closest which i can find:

[Convolution to blur the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891561/convolution-to-blur-the-image-produces-a-sketchy-output-image)

Know that the basic convolution algorithm is more or less the same, the affect changes only by the kernel values.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source [C# library](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) which provides methods to perform image convolution of simple filters. It would be an easy port to C.

The actual methods to perform convolution can be [found here](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Source/WriteableBitmapEx/WriteableBitmapFilterExtensions.cs). The BitmapContext class is used to just wrap a pointer to bitmap. I believe in C# this is treated as int*, so this code is operating on 4 bytes at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I created Image Convolution library for simple cases - https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Projects/tree/master/ImageConvolution.

It is pretty fast (OpenMP + SIMD).
Though I'm not an advanced programmer of something, just tried doing it to do first steps in utilizing SIMD. 
Still, from what can be seen in VS 2015, the CPU utilization is pretty good.

If you have ideas to make it even faster, I will be happy.

Feel free to use it in any manner you'd like.

Comment: Please do read [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)