# How to load nearby pixels using pointer

Tags: c++, opencv

Suppose i have an image matrix and i am at a particular pixel [say 4] like this:

```
 0  1  2  
 3 `4` 5  
 6  7  8
```

I am trying to cycle through all pixels and am attempting to access 0,1,2, 3,5 6,7,8 whose values i am storing in the array called `Pixel`.... here is my attempt at it using OpenCV, kindly tell me where am i going wrong.

I am using  pointer `temp_ptr` to access the IplImage `image`.

```
    uchar* temp_ptr=0 ;
    CvScalar Pixel[3][3];
    int rows=image->height,cols=image->width,row,col;
    for( row = 0; row < rows-2; ++row) 
    {
        for ( col = 0; col < cols-2; ++col) 
            {               
                    temp_ptr  = &((uchar*)(image->imageData + (image->widthStep*row)))[col*3];
                    for (int krow = -1 ; krow <= 1; krow++)
                    {
                        for (int kcol = -1; kcol <= 1; kcol++)
                        {       
                        temp_ptr  = &((uchar*)(image->imageData + (image->widthStep*row+krow)))[(col+kcol)*3];
                            for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
                            {
                                for(int j=0; j < 3; j++)
                                {
                                    for(int k=0; k < 3; k++)
                                    {
                                        Pixel[i][j].val[k]=temp_ptr[k];
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
             }
    }
```

I am not really sure how to load the sorrounding Pixels using`temp_ptr`, please help me out.

Comment: Having six nested for loops is almost certanly where you're going wrong. Do you need to cycle through all pixels or only those who can have all eight "neighbours"?

Comment: Only those who can have 8 neighbours.... also the way i access all pixels in the same way i will store values back by calculating the average values of all pixels and storing the new values from Color [RBG] array `Pixel`...into the center i.e. `4` pixel.

Comment: You have got a lot of useful tips. The most important is that you never write your result back into the image. And, I don't wanna sounde harsh, but as someone said "start to learn programming - your code is a complete mess". Everybodys code is a complete mess in the beginning, and I think that you should try to solve this on your own and try to understand what it is you're doing. You don't have troube with OpenCV. You have trouble writing algorithms. Once you get that into place - you'll be just fine! :-)

Comment: @danbystrom - I think you were wrong, my algorithm was just fine, and yes i know i am supposed to write the values back into the pixel, i just misplaced the braces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well sir, it sounds like you want to do convolution, and doing it this way when you have OpenCV at your fingertips is a bit like hammering a can opener on your Spaghettios to burst it open by blunt force.

In fact, what you're doing is almost exactly the output of [`cv::blur(src, dst, cv::Size(3,3))`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=convolution#boxfilter) except it also includes the center pixel in the average.

If you want to exclude the center pixel then you can create a custom kernel - just a matrix with appropriate weights:

```
[.125 .125 .125
 .125  0   .125
 .125 .125 .125 ]
```

and apply this to the image with [`cv::filter2d(src, dst, -1, kernel)`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=convolution#filter2d).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `image->imageData` is in RGB format, so there are 3 bytes for each pixel, you could do something like this:

```
int rows = image->height;
int cols = image->width;
uchar* temp_ptr = 0;

CvScalar pixels[8];

for (int col = 0; col < image->height - 2; col++) {
    temp_ptr = image->imageData + image->width * col + 1;
    for (int row = 0; row < image->width - 2; row++) {
        temp_ptr += row * 3;
        pixels[0].val = temp_ptr - width * 3 - 3;  // pixel 0 from your example
        pixels[1].val = temp_ptr - width * 3;      // 1
        pixels[2].val = temp_ptr - width * 3 + 3;  // 2
        pixels[3].val = temp_ptr - 3;              // 4
        pixels[4].val = temp_ptr + 3;              // etc...
        pixels[5].val = temp_ptr + width * 3 - 3;
        pixels[6].val = temp_ptr + width * 3;
        pixels[7].val = temp_ptr + width * 3 + 3;       

        // calculate averages here and store them somewhere (in a vector perhaps)
    }
}
```

Note I didn't test this code.

Comment: I don't know opencv. I'm merely guessing CvScalar.val is of type uchar[3], for example. I just wanted to give you an idea, not compilable ready-to-go code :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to start learning some programming. Your complete code is a mess. 
Some major problems I could quickly found:

- First of all you have to start your first two for loops from 1 (because you decrement by -1 when you apply the window) and you will end up reading some memory address that are not allocated.
- Second the first temp_ptr  = &((uchar*)(image->imageData + (image->widthStep*row)))[col*3] is useless so you can remove it.
- the other

  ```
  temp_ptr  = &((uchar*)(image->imageData + (image->widthStep*row+krow)))[(col+kcol)*3];
  ```

is having a small problem, the operator precedence, should be:

```
  temp_ptr  = &((uchar*)(image->imageData + image->widthStep*(row+krow))[(col+kcol)*3];
```

- you don't need the other 3 inside loops

Also is not clear what you want to do, you want to get the neighborhood of a specific pixel (then you need no loops) or you want to apply a kernel to each pixel from the image.

Comment: alinoz Your answer is wrong, i don't know who upvoted it... should know that the data type CvScalar is a struct that contains an array called `val` where you can store `RBG` values!

Comment: ok in this regards you are right. I will edit that part, but on the rest i'm right.